# Añadir icono instagram theme woodmart

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

Estoy tratando de añadir al tema para tiendas online de wordpress (woodmart) el icono de instagram para el método "follow". Pero no consigo establecerlo. He mirado la documentación  y según esta en la configuración de redes sociales se establece. Añado algunas capturas de donde he configurado la red social.

[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También he intentado por código establecer una nueva directiva para el tema y que admita una nueva red social, dentro del fichero `social.php` en la ruta `themes\woodmart\inc\shortcodes` esto lo que haría sería modificar el shortcode `[social_buttons]` pero sin éxito para mi, quizás no lo estoy haciendo bien.

¿Alguien ha añadido instagram a woodmart?

```
<?php if ( $type == 'share' && woodmart_get_opt( 'share_instagram' ) != ''): ?>
                    <a rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" href="<?php echo 'follow' === $type ? esc_url(woodmart_get_opt( 'instagram_link' )) : '' . $page_link; ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr( $target ); ?>" class="<?php if( $tooltip == "yes" ) echo 'wd-tooltip'; ?> wd-social-icon social-instagram">
                        <span class="wd-icon"></span>
                        <?php if ( $sticky ) : ?>
                            <span class="wd-icon-name"><?php esc_html_e('Instagram', 'woodmart') ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif ?>
```

gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he resuelto por código.

en el fichero:

```
\wp-content\themes\woodmart\inc\admin\settings\social.php
```

creé esta opción:

```
Options::add_field(
    array(
        'id'       => 'share_instagram',
        'name'     => esc_html__( 'Share in Instagram', 'woodmart' ),
        'type'     => 'switcher',
        'section'  => 'social_share',
        'default'  => '1',
        'priority' => 20,
        'class'    => 'xts-col-6',
    )
);
```

y esta:

```
Options::add_field(
    array(
        'id'       => 'instagram_link',
        'name'     => esc_html__( 'Instagram', 'woodmart' ),
        'type'     => 'text_input',
        'section'  => 'social_links',
        'default'  => '#',
        'priority' => 20,
        'class'    => 'xts-col-6',
    )
);
```

una es para mostrar el switch para compartir y la otra para mostrar el input para establecer el link de la página. Por defecto está activado y el enlace que pondrá es #. De esta manera conseguimos que se muestren los iconos. Salvo en compartir, que tenemos que tenemos que hacer una modificación en el fichero:

```
wp-content\themes\woodmart\inc\shortcodes\social.php
```

y modificar el comportamiento del icono de esta manera:

```
<?php if ( ( $type == 'share' && woodmart_get_opt('share_instagram') ) ): ?>
                    <a rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" href="<?php echo 'follow' === $type ? esc_url(woodmart_get_opt( 'instagram_link' )) : 'https://www.instagram_link.com/share?url=' . $page_link; ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr( $target ); ?>" class="<?php if( $tooltip == "yes" ) echo 'wd-tooltip'; ?> wd-social-icon social-instagram">
                        <span class="wd-icon"></span>
                        <?php if ( $sticky ) : ?>
                            <span class="wd-icon-name"><?php esc_html_e('Instagram', 'woodmart') ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif ?>
```

con esto lo que haremos es comprobar si tenemos checkeado el boton de compartir en instagram y si es así mostraremos el icono. Ahí configuraremos el enlace a nuestra página y hará un comportamiento similar a "Follow". Quizás es una chapuza lo que se ha hecho, pero funciona como se espera